# What is the class name/type of dr["MyColumn"] object in .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datarowview

I would like to create the function and pass the values to reduce the duplicate codes in my coding.

It will be called like this in GridView ItemDataBound event

```
DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
MyFunc(drv["HasDonePart1"]);
MyFunc(drv["HasDonePart2"]);
MyFunc(drv["HasDonePart3"]);
etc...
```

The function will be like the following

```
private void MyFunc ((ClassName) item)
{
    if (item == DBNULL.value)
    {
       //do something
    }
    else
    {
       string myValue = item.ToString();
       //do other things
    }
}
```

But I don't know what should I put in my method to accept the object.

Comment: Not enough information. The `DataRowView`'s indexer is declared as returning `object`; what it actually returns depends on the type of the column. You could use a debugger to find out, or print out `drv["HasDonePart1"].GetType().FullName`.

Comment: It returns System.DBNull.  Actually it returns the type of the object not the type of the value, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `MyFunc` to accept `object`, instead:

```
private void MyFunc(object item)
{
    if (item == DBNull.Value)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else if (item is string)
    {
    }
    else if (item is decimal)
    {
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DataRowView.Item indexed property returns object, so that's what your method should take as parameter. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k5w061k(v=vs.110).aspx